# Как к своему php файлу подключить функции?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Создал плагин WP, в папке с плагином создал второй php файл, который выполняет post cURL запрос и к нему **разрешен прямой доступ**.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

$body = array(
    'id' => '1',
    'user_id' => '100'
);

$args = array(
    'body' => $body
);

$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://site.ru/test.php', $args );
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
echo $body;
```

Как обойтись без подключения строки `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');`?

Писал в WP, меня отправили на страницу с рекомендациями:

> Если вам нужно иметь ‘страницы’ прямой доступ с помощью внешнего сервиса, то вы должны использовать query_vars и/или переписать правила, чтобы создать виртуальную страницу, которая вызывает функцию.
>
> Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с плагинами справочник по API для получения дополнительной информации: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
>
> если вы пытаетесь использовать AJAX, пожалуйста, прочитайте это:
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
>
> **Для других возможностей, или лучше понять, почему мы не разрешаем это, прочитайте это: http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/**

Прочел, чувствую, что там есть решение моей задачи, но как реализовать не понял. В примере речь идет о подключении css и js, ничего полезного там выяснить не смог, понял, что подключать `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');` нельзя, т.к. это грузит всю систему wp и путь к файлу может быть другим у разных пользователей wp.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Как мне изменить скрипт, чтобы он не загружал постоянно ядро wordpress?

Если второй php файл подключить к основному файлу плагина, сразу выполняется cURL post запрос и вместо всего сайта отображается результат выполнения cURL.

Спасибо!

Comment: Если это плагин, то нужно не "к своему php файлу подключить функции", а использовать функции ВП в нём.  Плагин УЖЕ подключён к ВП, если сделан в соответствии с требованиями.

Comment: Да, но как в нем использовать функции wp без подключения `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');`?

Comment: Надо думать не об отдельном  "файле", а о плагине, как цельной сущности. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

Вам достаточно для удачной работы `wp_remote_post()` и `wp_remote_retrieve_body()` подключить файл, где описаны даные хуки, а именно `wp-includes/http.php` (для версии WordPress 4.9.8). 
Тоесть:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/http.php');
```

Comment: Так будет 500. `wp_remote_post()` использует `wp-includes/class-http.ph` как минимум. Возможно, что-то ещё. Вы бы протестировали свой ответ.

Comment: Для  4.9.8 таки `wp-includes/http.php` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post

Comment: Изначально версия wp не известна. Мне предложили пример как использовать встроенную обертку CURL в плагинах: https://github.com/tommcfarlin/wp-remote-post-example Видимо плагин сильно устарел,  пока не понял как реализовать, но `require` там точно нет.

Comment: @NikPashchuk не понял коммента. Я в код wp_remote_get() посмотрел, вижу, что он требует

Comment: @MicroRu Можете как варинт попробывать запускать исполнение функции через параметр `GET` . Например, если Ваш плагин имеет свой класс на констукторе 
`if ( isset( $_GET['run_my_script'] ) ) {
   add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'moya_funcya' ), 10 );
}`
В даном примере будет весь функционал WordPress, если нужно загружать ранее, порядок выполнения хуков https://wp-kama.ru/hooks/actions-order

Comment: Nik Pashchuk, спасибо, сейчас попробую разобраться.

Comment: У плагина класс есть, код в этом вопросе - 2 файл плагина (код отображен полностью), он имеет прямой доступ (http://site.ru/wp-content/plugins/widget/includes/index.php) и в результате на сайте wp должен открывать страницы (html) с другого сайта, результат работы cURL. В корне сайта, в .htaccess прописано правило для данного файла. Не знаю, получится запускать исполнение через get.